QML MouseArea not recognizing touch events reliably when small and near other objects
I just started programming an automotive touch screen (3D50VT-200) and was having a rather fun time with it until I started noticing some inconsistent touch behavior. At first, I thought it may be a hardware issue, but it seems to be caused by the size of the touch area in QML. I made a small test program that changes the color of the square when you click/touch 2 of them. The code below works, as long as the size of the Rectangle element is about 100 pixels and becomes completely unusable when the button is 50 pixels wide. Strangely, if I place a single square by itself in the Row, then it works even at 50 pixels. It seems QT is filtering the touch events somehow or there's some contention between event handlers.
Is this specific to my platform or is this a general issue and how can I fix it (besides making my buttons huge)?
Using QT 5.15.3 , QTQuick 2.9

import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import Disp3DXX 1.0
import GhCamera 1.0

//
//    width  x height
// 5
// 7     800 x 480
// 10.4 1024 x 768
// 10.1 1280 x 800
//

Window {
    id      : root                   
    visible : false                   // don't show rendering... wait for big reveal
    width   : disp3dxx.getWidth()     // actual screen width  -- varies by display size
    height  : disp3dxx.getHeight()    // actual screen width  -- varies by display size
    color   : "yellow"                // needs to be set to avoid quick flash when made visible

    //
    // declare the Disp3DXX and GhCamera classes and give them a reference id
    //
    Disp3DXX { id : disp3dxx    }
    // GhCamera { id : inputCamera }

    Row {
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       spacing: 50
       Rectangle {
           width: 100
           height: 100
           color: "red"
           radius: 10
       }

       Rectangle {
           width: 100 // STOPS WORKING WHEN ABOUT 50PX x 50PX
           height: 100
           color: "green"
           radius: 10

           MouseArea {
               anchors.fill: parent
               onClicked: {
                   parent.color = "red"
                   changeColorTimerGn.start()
                   console.log("Clicked on blue square")
               }
           }

           Timer {
               id: changeColorTimerGn
               interval: 200 // Default interval
               repeat: false
               onTriggered: {
                     // Change the color when the timer triggers
                     parent.color = "green"
               }
           }


       }

       Rectangle {
           id : blueId
           width: 100 // STOPS WORKING WHEN ABOUT 50PX x 50PX
           height: 100
           color: "blue"
           radius: 10

           MouseArea {
               anchors.fill: blueId
               onClicked: {
                  parent.color = "red"
                   changeColorTimerBl.start()
                   console.log("Clicked on blue square")
               }
           }

           Timer {
               id: changeColorTimerBl
               interval: 200 // Default interval
               repeat: false
               onTriggered: {
                     // Change the color when the timer triggers
                     parent.color = "blue"
               }
           }


       }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
                    root.visible       = true
                    disp3dxx.lcdBacklight (50)  // initially turn on 50% 
                    console.log("Hell, world!")
                }
}   // end Window


Tried connecting a mouse to the screen and the small square responds to mouse clicks
Tried isolating the square and it responds to mouse clicks
Ran a bundled example that came with the screen and all small buttons had similar issue
I expect the touch events to work reliably irrespective of other squares nearby


Give the MouseArea a negative margin (anchors.margins: -50) or use a TapHandler and then set its tap margin.

This works, I still feel it's being too conservative in registering a touch. On my phone things usually work at a single flick, here I have to be very careful and usually tap buttons  multiple times before they finally work. Oddly, this can't be a hardware issue, because the mouse cursor follows each tap, but QML just doesn't consider that a "good enough" touch. So I was wondering if there's some global "suck less" setting in Qt.

If the mouse clicks are working, then it's not a software issue either. However, using a click should be more precise, as it should have a press and release together. Therefore, any error on touching can cause it to fail. So, for testing, let's try using just onPressed and see if it makes a difference or not.

It does catch it more often with onPressed. I think I got it for now, I will use margins.
